# determine two interpretation for predicate logical formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have to find two interpretation so that a formula alpha is $$ \Im1(\alpha)=0$$  $$\Im 2(\alpha)=1$$
in $$\mathbb N$$
The given formulas are:

$$
\alpha1 = \forall x \forall y \forall z \forall u ((P(u,x) \land Q(x,y,z)) \to P(u,z))
$$
$$
\alpha2 = \forall x \forall y (P(x,y) \land P(f(x),f(y)) \to P(x,f(x)) \land P(y,f(y)))
$$

i dont know how i can find interpretations so that the formulas are $$ \Im1(\alpha)=0$$  $$\Im 2(\alpha)=1$$

Comment: Wait, so you have *two* $\alpha$'s?

Comment: Yes but i have edited it. I have to find $\Im 1(\alpha 1)=0$, $\Im 2(\alpha 1)=1$ and $\Im 1(\alpha 2)=0$, $\Im 2(\alpha 2)=1$